# SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError: failed to locate name happens only on gunicorn

Tags: python, heroku, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn

Okay, so I have the following. In `user/models.py`:

```
class User(UserMixin, SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    password = Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
    departments = relationship("Department",secondary="user_department_relationship_table", back_populates="users")
```

and in `department/models.py`:

```
user_department_relationship_table=db.Table('user_department_relationship_table',
                             db.Column('department_id', db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('departments.id'), nullable=False),
                             db.Column('user_id',db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False),
                             db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('department_id', 'user_id') )


class Department(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'departments'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    short_name = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    users = relationship("User", secondary=user_department_relationship_table,back_populates="departments")
```

Using the flask development server locally this works totally fine. However, once I deploy to the standard python buildpack on heroku, the `cpt/app.py` loads both modules to register their blueprints:

```
from cpt import (
        public, user, department
        )

...


def register_blueprints(app):
    app.register_blueprint(public.views.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(user.views.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(department.views.blueprint)
    return None
```

and eventually errors out with the following:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper
>   Mapper|User|users, expression 'user_department_relationship_table'
>   failed to locate a name ("name 'user_department_relationship_table' is
>   not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this
>   relationship() to the  class after
>   both dependent classes have been defined.

I'd like to know if there's a better way to organize these parts to avoid this error obviously, but I'm more curious why this organization works fine on the development server but blows up something fierce on gunicorn/heroku.

Comment: do you have two databases, one on heroku one on local? It seems to complain the table doesn't exist in your production environment.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes This seems to happen before the app tries to talk to the db at all. But, there is an alembic migration to add the user_department_relationship_table that I've run without issue in both environments.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't explain the discrepancy between heroku and the dev server, but I got the error to go away by changing the Department mode from

```
users = relationship("Department",secondary="user_department_relationship_table", back_populates="users")
```

to

```
users = relationship("User", secondary=user_department_relationship_table, backref="departments")
```

which sets up the User model automatically which in turn means I can delete any mention of Department and the relationship table on that end.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Struggling with the same issue, in my case the test environment doesn't error out which makes it really difficult to know about it before a prod deploy 